# Sqlite3: InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 -probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi2

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO sensors values(?,?,?)",
((format(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')),
 pydata['id'], pydata['data'])))
```

The output:

```
$ python filterUDPListen.py 
Time: 23-01-2016 12:59:13 Device: AA Data: TEMP017.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "filterUDPListen.py", line 71, in <module>
c.execute("INSERT INTO sensors values(?,?,?)",((datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')), pydata['id'], pydata['data']))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

I keep getting different error while altering this code. Can anyone point me in the right direction off what is wrong here?

The total code:

```
while True:
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024*8)
pydata = json.loads(data)
if pydata['type'] == 'WirelessMessage':
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if pydata['network'] != sys.argv[2]:
            continue
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        if pydata['id'] == sys.argv[1]:
    now = time()
            timediff = now - lasttime
    lasttime = now
            print("Device: {} Data: {} Time: {} Network: {} Timesince: {}".format(pydata['id'], pydata['data'][0], pydata['timestamp'], pydata['network'], timediff))
    else:
        print("Time: {} Device: {} Data: {}".format (datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S'), pydata['id'], pydata['data'][0]))
        c.execute("INSERT INTO sensors values(?,?,?)",((format(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')), pydata['id'], pydata['data'])))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: what errors are you getting? Please show the exact error you get with the code you've posted.

Comment: I don't understand why you've got that call to `format` there.

Comment: Added the exact error @BryanOakley

Comment: @DanielRoseman i'm just starting to understand the code. That format is given previously in the file. So i just copy pasted that.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024*8)
pydata = json.loads(data)
if pydata['type'] == 'WirelessMessage':
    if len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if pydata['network'] != sys.argv[2]:
            continue
    if "AWAKE" in (pydata['data'][0]):
        print "Awake"
    elif "SLEEPING" in (pydata['data'][0]):
        print "Sleeping"
    elif "BATT" in (pydata['data'][0]):
        print "Found 'is' in the string."
        temp = pydata['data'][0]
        date_mmddyyyy = strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())
        temperature_location = pydata['id']
        data = {'date': date_mmddyyyy, 'value': temp}
        result = requests.put(firebase_url + '/' + temperature_location + '/BattLevel.json',data=json.dumps(data))
        print 'Record inserted. Result Code = ' + str(result.status_code) + ',' + result.text
    else:
        temp = pydata['data'][0]
        temperature = temp.replace("TEMP", "")
        date_mmddyyyy = strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())
        temperature_location = pydata['id']
        data = {'date': date_mmddyyyy, 'value': temperature}
        result = requests.post(firebase_url + '/' + temperature_location + '/temperature.json',
                               data=json.dumps(data))
        print 'Record inserted. Result Code = ' + str(result.status_code) + ',' + result.text
        print (pydata['data'][0])
```

I ended up with this and everything is working now.
Added the time to a variable first.